# Form validation not returning errors

Tags: symfony

Im trying to get backend form validation working but its letting empty fields get through when I remove the frontend validation.

Im following the documentation and wondering if anyone else is having this issue.

```
# config/packages/framework.yaml
framework:
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CommentRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CommentRepository::class)
 */
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $name;
```

```
<?php
namespace App\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CommentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, ['required' => true])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, ['required' => true])
            ->add('body', TextareaType::class, ['required' => true])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class);
    }
}
```

and the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Comment;
use App\Form\Type\CommentType;
use Knp\Component\Pager\PaginatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class CommentController extends AbstractController
{
    public function create(Request $request, $parent_id)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    ...
```

and the form itself is

```
{{ form_start(form, {'action': path('app.comment.create', { parent_id: parent_id })}) }}

    <div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.name, 'Name') }}
                {{ form_widget(form.name, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.email, 'Email') }}
                {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form_label(form.body, 'Comment') }}
                {{ form_widget(form.body, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{
        form_row(form.submit, {
            'label': button_text ?? 'Add Comment',
            'attr': { 'class': 'form-control btn-primary btn-blue' }
        })
    }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

The form is passing flying colours, even though they are empty.

Id appreciate any help at all on this. I'm coming over from Laravel >_<

EDIT:

it seems form validation does not work with a redirect. my bad.

Comment: is passing flying colours ... means, you end up inside the if block? or is there just no error output? generally, there is no error bubbling, meaning, `{{ form_error(form.body) }}` will hold the error for the body (to which the error is attached), while `{{ form_error(form) }}` might be empty. see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling (default: false) and https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form.html#accessing-form-errors consider using `{{ form_row(form.body) }}` and a bootstrap form theme.

Comment: @Jakumi yeah I end up inside the if block and if i `dd($form->getErrors())` it returns empty.

Comment: i guess it´s not working because there are no ORM annotations on the name field, should be sth. like `* @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems form validation does not work with a redirect. my bad. I should have provided the full controller.